# Pinescript 5: my strategy skips only some stoploss and I don't understand why

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, back-testing

In this simple code for pinescript v5 I tried to backtest a strategy in which the stop loss are at 2% of my order and same thing for take profit.

When I run this for backtesting in tradingview, I realized that in some unexpected case, my stop loss was purely ignore. This change the result of my strategy ovviously and this is not acceptable.

I wrote to support in Trading View and they have confirmed that my code is correct but it does not work properly.

Here's my pinescript V5 simple code

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true)
deviazione=3.0
[vwap,upper,lower] = ta.vwap(hlc3,anchor=timeframe.change("1D"),stdev_mult=deviazione)

sl= 0.02
tp= 0.02
if ta.crossunder(low, lower)
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Enter Long",limit= strategy.position_avg_price*(1+tp),stop=strategy.position_avg_price*(1-sl))

plot(strategy.position_avg_price*(1+tp),title= "Take_profit",color=color.green)
plot(strategy.position_avg_price*(1-sl),title= "Stop_loss",color=color.red)
plot(upper, color=color.fuchsia,title= "Upper")
plot(lower,color=color.rgb(255, 157, 0),title= "Lower")
```

This is the strangest results that backtesting gave to me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0acAV.png)

Here the trend of the price. You can noticed that the stoploss was not respected.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVxWi.png)

I expected to see my strategy close correctly my position like in this operation of the same script in the same backtest. I attach you a screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoPG5.png)

Answer (score 1):

Set *strategy.exit* when *strategy.position_size* > 0

Something like that:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Enter Long",limit= strategy.position_avg_price*(1+tp),stop=strategy.position_avg_price*(1-sl))
```